Cloudformation: Unable to publish test message to notification target
Trying to create cloudformation stack that creates an autoscaling group with one spot instance
and that instance should automatically attach a volume using lifecycle policy hook lambda function
here is my stack:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Auto Scaling with Spot Instances and Lifecycle Hooks

Parameters:
  ImageId:
    Type: String
    Default: 'ami-xxxxxx'
    Description: AMI ID for the instances.
  VolumeId:
    Type: String
    Default: 'vol-xxxxxxxxx'
    Description: EBS Volume ID to attach.
  AvailabilityZone:
    Type: String
    Default: 'xx-xxxxxxx-xx'
    Description: Availability Zone for the instance.
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: String
    Default: 'sg-xxxxxxxxx'
    Description: Security Group ID for the instances.
  KeyName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    Description: The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instances.

Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - autoscaling.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: MyPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:AttachVolume
                  - ec2:DetachVolume
                Resource: '*'

  MyAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones:
        - !Ref AvailabilityZone
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref MyLaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt MyLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: '1'
      DesiredCapacity: '1'

  MyLaunchTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: !Ref ImageId
        InstanceType: t2.xlarge
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup
        InstanceMarketOptions:
          MarketType: spot
          SpotOptions:
            MaxPrice: '0.1'

  LifecycleHookFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt MyRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import time
          def handler(event, context):
            ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
            if event['detail-type'] == 'EC2 Instance-launch Lifecycle Action':
              # Retry logic to ensure volume is detached before attaching
              while True:
                response = ec2.describe_volumes(VolumeIds=[event['detail']['VolumeId']])
                if response['Volumes'][0]['State'] == 'available':
                  break
                time.sleep(10)
              ec2.attach_volume(VolumeId=event['detail']['VolumeId'], InstanceId=event['detail']['EC2InstanceId'], Device='/dev/sdf')
            elif event['detail-type'] == 'EC2 Instance-terminate Lifecycle Action':
              ec2.detach_volume(VolumeId=event['detail']['VolumeId'], InstanceId=event['detail']['EC2InstanceId'])
            return 'Success'
      Runtime: python3.8
      Timeout: 120


  LifecycleHook:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook'
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: !Ref MyAutoScalingGroup
      LifecycleTransition: autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING
      NotificationTargetARN: !GetAtt LifecycleHookFunction.Arn
      RoleARN: !GetAtt MyRole.Arn
      HeartbeatTimeout: 3600
      DefaultResult: CONTINUE

Outputs:
  AutoScalingGroupName:
    Description: Name of the Auto Scaling Group
    Value: !Ref MyAutoScalingGroup


but during creation getting this error:
Resource handler returned message: "Unable to publish test message to notification target arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:yyyy:function:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx using IAM role arn:aws:iam::yyyyy:role/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Please check your target and role configuration and try to put lifecycle hook again. (Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxx-ce2a-4d25-9986-yy)" (RequestToken: xxxxxxx-b982-bb06-0fe2-yy, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

I don't see the permissions to invoke a lambda in your template.  You will need to give the autoscaling service permissions to invoke the lambda function.  Look at this guide for more details.

Quick edit to better match the guide instructions.
